# java - Inheritence, make a new class

Tags: java, object, inheritance, interface

How can i make a new circle class from these code, with the radius and midpoint of `(x,y)` that implemented the interface canvas?

```
public abstract class GraphicalObject { 
protected int x;
protected int y;
protected int color;

public abstract void setColor(bye r, byte g, byte b);
public abstract void setPosition(int x, int y);
}

public interface Canvas {
public void draw(GraphicalObject object); 
}
```

Comment: Every GraphicalObject should probably be drawable, I would implement Canvas at GraphicalObject level, not at Circle level.

Comment: yeah, that's true … but you need to learn to stand up on your feet before you can running right?

Comment: I know I know, but it's still a valid point.

Comment: Then if you don't mind, what about trying to solve this question that seems so easy on your sight instead of talking about other problems?

Comment: You have 2 valid answers, you will have to write the setColor, setPosition and draw methods in the Circle class, respecting the method signature.

Comment: Here are some details about inheritance, which you haven't bothered to search for : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
public class Circle extends GraphicalObject  implements Canvas {
  // implement all your method
}
```

Edit: Make a new class from that abstract code:

> You can not instantiate an abstract class or an interface - you can instantiate one of their subclasses/implementers.

You can create `Anonymous Class` for your `GraphicalObject` class like:

```
GraphicalObject object = new GraphicalObject() {
    public void setColor(bye r, byte g, byte b){
      // an implementation of an interface method
    }

    public void setPosition(int x, int y){
      // an implementation of an interface method
    }
 };
```

Comment: i knew this, but don't get to know to implement the method.

Comment: Sry @lawZ I'm not able to understand your question what it means "i just tried to figured out to make an inheritance object from it".

Comment: sorry, it's a wrong comment. The thing is i just want to make a new class from that abstract code as the inheritance object.

Comment: @lawZ see the ans, let me know if it helps.

Comment: yeah, thanks man! I just get confused a little bit on some part. This seems so easy

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Circle extends GraphicalObject  implements Canvas
```